# typescript: remove compiler error on non existent object properties

Tags: angular, typescript

I have just started on angular 2 with typescript and I am coming from a js background.

I have the following code:

```
export class AddunitsComponent implements OnInit {
  public centers:any; 
  constructor(){
  this.centers = {};
}}
```

Now I have a view with the following input:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="centers.name">
```

When I compile the app using `ng build --prod`, I get an error `property name does not exist on type 'Object'`

Then I got to know that each property needs to be defined as an interface or in the constructor.

And this is a problem for me now because I have already made all the views which are using lot of inputs for data entry and I was testing without the prod flag, which did not raise any errors.

Is there a way I can disable this check at compile time for production?

Comment: you can fix it by defining the type in place like this `public centers:{name: string};`

Comment: Are you sure you haven't used type `Object` anywhere? Type `any` shouldn't raise any problems in this case

Answer (score 0):

Make it optional by using this

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="centers?.name">
```

OR

```
<input type="text" *ngIf='centers?.name' [(ngModel)]="centers.name">
```

Comment: Safe navigation operator doesn't work on two-way bindings AFAIK

Comment: @echonax , thanks I just updated it again , I was just missed that point.

Comment: @VivekDoshi getting : "Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment" error if I use your way.